# Avoid array loops sonar issue: system.arraycopy

Tags: arrays, sonarqube

I would like to use SysteM.arraycopy to make the below method faster. But as of my knowledge, Arraycopy cannot involve any such complicated logic.

```
for (int c = 0; c < newRow.length && c < target[r].length; ++c)
{
    target[r][c] = newRow[c];
}
```

So any help would be welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite that using `System.arraycopy`.
This about it this way:

- You want to copy starting from index 0 of `newRow`
- You want to copy starting from index 0 into `target[r]`
- You want to copy at most `newRow.length` or `target[r].length` elements, whichever is smaller

Like this:

```
System.arraycopy(newRow, 0, target[r], 0, Math.min(newRow.length, target[r].length));
```